# Tracing other users in mvc application with Glimpse

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nuget

I am trying to trace my MVC application using Glimpse.
I must say that I was very impressed with what glimpse can provide as a tracing tool.
But I cant figure out that **How will i get the trace information, when some user, from some other location  used my application?** It always just shows my own trace information.

If this is the limitation of Glimpse, what's the point!!

---

Basically I just want to avoid asking users for their credentials just to try the operation which caused problem and then get access to trace information. I wan't to trace for all the requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with Glimpse. From what I understand it's mainly a debugging tool for your own requests with lots of server information thrown in.

Have you looked into [Elmah](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx)?